# How to configure Mapbox Vector Tiles (pbf files) cache in NGINX

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, cache, pbf, nginx

I am using a Geoserver to serve Vector Tiles which are used by Mapbox JS Clients. To reduce the requests to the Geoserver I want to implement a caching functionality.
As webserver I use a NGINX. I tried to implement a cache for the pbf files but I cannot see that the caching works.

What do I need to configure in NGINX to cache pbf files?

Comment: this seems more a Nginx question than a GeoServer question so it might be better asked on stackoverflow

Comment: It is not a usual content and here I have audience with similiar problems

Comment: @DarkFoo did this get answered elsewhere?

Comment: @ziggy no, I did not find a solution.